# Nginx reverse proxy throws 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm new to using Nginx as a reverse proxy, and here is my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location /myip/ {
    proxy_pass http://checkip.dyndns.com/;
    proxy_set_header Host            http://checkip.dyndns.com/;
  }
}
```

and this line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is active:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

I was expecting to see a page about my IP address when I visited `http://localhost/myip/`, but I got 404 instead. Any ideas why so? Meanwhile `http://localhost` is correctly showing nginx's welcoming page.

### More details about my env:

- Clean debian VM in GCP
- Nginx installed via `sudo apt install nginx`
- server status (`sudo systemctl status nginx`) is looking good:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-03-08 01:27:50 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 4237 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exite
d, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3342 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
S)
  Process: 4242 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4239 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4244 (nginx)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─4244 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           ├─4245 nginx: worker process
           └─4246 nginx: worker process
Mar 08 01:27:50 marqeta-proxy-test systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Mar 08 01:27:50 marqeta-proxy-test systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Mar 08 01:27:50 marqeta-proxy-test systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: The host header should be `checkip.dyndns.com` and not `http://checkip.dyndns.com/`.

Comment: thanks @CherryDT, however updating that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Hm actually, I think the fact that you see nginx' welcome page is unexpected. This server configuration should actually deliver a 404 on the index page since there is no index document defined. Try removing nginx' default vhost configuration!

Comment: Whoa @CherryDT, once I remove `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, things are looking good!!